# CodeIgniter Mail + Exim4

Tags: email, codeigniter, exim4

i've set up Exim4 on my Ubuntu machine.

I've started learning CodeIgniter and when sending an e-mail through there email library i get the following if I ask for the debug status. Looks OK i suppose, but i never receive e-mail on jandante@telenet.be. Also doesn't work for jandante.meulemeester@gmail.com, anyone has an idea?

```
220 Concept-IT ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1; Fri, 3 Sep 2010 18:15:59 +0200; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]

hello: 250-Concept-IT Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP

from: 250 2.1.0 ... Sender ok

to: 250 2.1.5 ... Recipient ok

data: 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

250 2.0.0 o83GFx3a021848 Message accepted for delivery

quit: 221 2.0.0 Concept-IT closing connection

Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: smtp

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Fri, 3 Sep 2010 18:15:59 +0200
From: "Concept-IT" 
Return-Path: 
To: jandante@telenet.be
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Uw_nieuw_wachtwoord_voor_Concept-IT_CRM?=
Reply-To: "info@concept-it.be" 
X-Sender: info@concept-it.be
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4c811f3f98626@concept-it.be>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Uw gebruikersnaam is: liesbeth en uw wachtwoord is: 6ZiKJxD.
```

Comment: i see now that it was still using sendmail (which was installed before, now I have Exim4). But still the same problem, it says the e-mail was sent, but I don't receive anything. The new output can be found here: http://pastebin.com/qu9zx074

Comment: Further investigation (/var/log/mail.log) learned me that my ISP (TELENET) doesn't allow me to send mail from my own server. I'll have a look at setting server up to send mail through Google Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in my comments my problem comes from my ISP. Which doesn't allow me to send mail from my server.

I've followed the following tutorial to make Exim4 send mail through Google Mail: http://www.manu-j.com/blog/wordpress-exim4-ubuntu-gmail-smtp/.

Works like a charm.